# Absolutely placed TouchableOpacity not clickable if another TouchableOpacity is beneath it

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, absolute

I am trying to make a dropdown list, which looks like when the dropdown is visible
[image]

when the dropdown is not visible, the dropdown items are made of TouchableOpacity imported from react-native-gesture-handler, placed in a view which is placed absolutely with respect to a view containing the white text box and the dropdown button,

[image]

the problem is, the touch event is consumed by the submit button and not the dropdown item above it IN ANDROID.

I have applied zIndex to every item and the view containing the touchable items, further elevation is also set to a value grated than the button below it.

Comment: I struggle with this issue myself a lot…
Did you try using TouchableHighLight  from react-native-gesture-handle for the submit button too?

Comment: Submit button is using the native touchableopacity, i have solved the problem using absolute positioning and placing the dropdown component just before the ending of the jsx fragment, for its position i calculate the position of the display box and offset it accordingly, this works but makes it harder to extract components

Answer (score 0):

I never understood the reason to import the native Components from react-native-gesture-handler, often did it by error from autocompletion in VS code and often had problems with it. I would just import TouchableOpacity from react-native.

Edit:

Furthermore Android can not handle touch events if the containing view has a different position.

Comment: Native TouchableOpacity is unable to catch touch events when absolutely placed :[, when imported from react-native-gesture-handler, works fine but still unable to compete for Touch when any other is placed beneath